# Changing border color with help of JQuery & Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

Is it possible to change border color of Textbox if that Username is not available in MySQL with help of Ajax & JQuery with PHP? I've searched a lot on web but all I get is how to change innerHTML of div using Ajax which is useful if I want to show Tick or Cross image. Please Help

Answer (score 2):

make ajax call like below and pass user name with formdata and check with database.if you can't get username from your database then send flag 'false' in response.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "your_url to post",
            data: formdata,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (msg) {
                 if(msg=='false')
                     $('#tbxControl').attr('style','border:1px solid #000');
            }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check jQuery documentation "how to change style of element"
2. Check jQuery documentation "how to send ajax request"
3. Combine 1) and 2): send a request that checks username, in callback function
   adapt style of element

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy. You can change the border based on an ajax response; to change the border, use the css method on a jQuery object.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/mCk6z/

```
jQuery(function(){
    $('#username').css({'border': '1px solid #000'});

});
```

Comment: Better than styling the element directly, would be to add a class like "error", and format the element via that in the desired way.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this tutorial](http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/checking-username-availability-with-ajax-using-jquery/).

If you go to the *Jquery part*, after the line 40, you just need to add:

```
$('#username').css({border: "1px solid red"});
```

Hope it helps!
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Solution which worked for me :)

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="eMailTxt" id="eMailTxt" class="texttt" placeholder="Email Address" onChange="showUser(this.value)" />
```

**AJAX**

```
function showUser(str)
{
    if (str=="")
    {
        $('#eMailTxt').css({'border':'blue 2px solid'});
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                if (xmlhttp.responseText=="false")
                {
                    $("#eMailTxt").css({'border':'red 2px solid'});
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#eMailTxt").css({'border':'green 2px solid'});
                }
            }
        }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","login.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $q=$_GET["q"];
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_db");
    $check="SELECT Email FROM persons WHERE EMAIL = '".$q."'";
    $data=mysqli_query($con,$check);
    $result=mysqli_fetch_array($data);
    if ($result[0]==$q)
    {
        echo "true";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "false";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a bad username class

```
.badUsername{
Border-colour: <colour of your choice>
}
```

Then in the ajax success or fail function you can apply this class to the textbox

```
$(#<TextboxID>).addClass(badUsername);
```

(You can also use removeClass or hasClass to perform checks on the element)

Another option is to adjust the style directly in the success or fail function

```
$(#<TextboxID>).css(“border-colour: <colour of your choice>;”);
```